# Completion of a metric space vs. field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Given a field $F$ and a metric $\mu$, is the completion of $F$ with respect to $\mu$ always a field?  Additionally, is there an algebraic field extension of $F$ that is isomorphic to the completion of $F$ by $\mu$?

Comment: Of course not, because the metric need not have anything to do with the field. As far as the metric is concerned, $F$ is just a set. Things might get interesting if the field operations are required to be continuous for the metric.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_(algebra) (especially the part about completion - though the completed field is not an algebraic extension)

Comment: For point (2), note that $\mathbb R$ is *not* an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jack M answered the question in the comments above.  I am posting this answer just so that I can close out the question.

Answer:

> Jack M wrote:
>
> Of course not, because the metric need not have anything to do with
>   the field. As far as the metric is concerned, $F$ is just a set.
>   Things might get interesting if the field operations are required to
>   be continuous for the metric.
>
> For point (2), note that $\Bbb{R}$ is not an algebraic extension of
>   $\Bbb{Q}$